Angular Component Testing - How to check for a nested element
This loading-overlay component is used in other components through a service
<div *ngIf="isLoading$ | async" class="loading-overlay">
  <mat-progress-bar color="accent" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
</div>

for example,
<app-loading-overlay class="special-position"></app-loading-overlay>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row py-3">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 mb-3">
      <mat-card> ...

like this. And it's called inside components like this
this.loadingOverlayService.startLoading();
this.loadingOverlayService.stopLoading();

using this service
export class LoadingOverlayService {
  private loading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  // Observable to be used in components
  isLoading$ = this.loading.asObservable();

  startLoading() {
    this.loading.next(true);
  }

  stopLoading() {
    this.loading.next(false);
  }
}

It works like it is intended to work, But in this test in spec.ts file
  it('should display loading overlay when loading service is active', () => {
    loadingOverlayService.startLoading();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const loadingOverlay = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(
      'app-loading-overlay'
    );
    expect(loadingOverlay).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should not display loading overlay when loading service is inactive', () => {

    loadingOverlayService.stopLoading();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const loadingOverlay = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('app-loading-overlay');
    expect(loadingOverlay).toBeNull();
  });

Both cases return true cause I'm directly checking whether the parent component exits. What I want to check is that only .loading-overlay shows when it needs to.
Basically what I want to check is this loading-overlay class is working correctly with startLoading and stopLoading methods.
I tried this
fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('[loading-overlay]');
and bunch of other ways but couldn't figure out

You need to test the element that is hidden by the @if (element with the class .loading-overlay), not the component selector, since it will always be displayed.
  it('should display loading overlay when loading service is active', () => {
    loadingOverlayService.startLoading();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const loadingOverlay = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(
      '.loading-overlay'
    ); // <- changed here!
    expect(loadingOverlay).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should not display loading overlay when loading service is inactive', () => {
    loadingOverlayService.stopLoading();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const loadingOverlay = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.loading-overlay') || null; // <- changed here!
    expect(loadingOverlay).toBeNull();
  });


First test fails because it generates a null.
expect(received).toBeTruthy() Received: null
114 |       '.loading-overlay'       115 |     ); // <- changed here!     > 116 |     expect(loadingOverlay).toBeTruthy();           |                            ^       117 |   });

@chabiya.99 please replicate the issue on this stackblitz and share back!
